# What does this regular expression mean in Android augmented reality?

Tags: android, regex, pattern-matching, augmented-reality

I found a program in Android that claims to return marker positions in AR ("AR_speaker") and uses native code (jni). My problem is in the `markerInfo` class. I can't understand the meaning of this regular expression:
`^id=(\\d+):name=(.+):pos\\[0\\]=([\\d.]+):pos\\[1\\]=([\\d.]+)$`

```
public class MarkerInfo implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private static final Pattern REGEX = Pattern.compile("^id=(\\d+):name=(.+):pos\\[0\\]=([\\d.]+):pos\\[1\\]=([\\d.]+)$");
  private Integer id;
  private String fileName;
  private Float[] pos = new Float[3];

  public MarkerInfo(String markerStr) {
    Matcher m = REGEX.matcher(markerStr);
    if (!m.find()) throw new RuntimeException("not markerInfo string : " + markerStr);
    id = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    fileName = m.group(2);
    pos[0] = Float.parseFloat(m.group(3));
    pos[1] = Float.parseFloat(m.group(4));
    //pos[2]=Float.parseFloat(m.group(5));
  }

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
  }

  public Float[] getPos() {
    return pos;
  }
}
```

My other question is where are these data stored? Do any patterns used in AR have these data? In which file? (For example, in marker.patt?)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Regular Expressions ^ means "start of expression or deny character but in this case is start of expression", then this is what the expression is looking for in the markerStr, is looking for the characters "id=" followed by one or more decimal characters followed by ":name=" followed by a group one or more characters of any kind (thats what .+ mean) followed by ":pos[0]=" followed by one or more decimal characters or dot (thats what [\d.]+ mean) followed by "pos[1]=" followed by one or more decimal characters or dot (thats what [\d.]+ mean) and $ means the end of the regular expression...

Hope this help, and anyway i recommed you to read about Regex, they are extremely good tool to find patterns in a string, that's what they are using it for in this case...

Regards!

Comment: :thanks! i understand your explanation,but i have some other question that i think is related to AR:these data(name ,pos and...)are stored in markerstr?where they stored? every marker have these data?

Comment: Of course I can't tell where they are getting that information from, all i can tell is that they are looking for the pattern i just explained in the markerStr (which i expect would contain that info) ...